# Woocomemrce order and registration fileds to UPPERCASE

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration

I have to transform all the registration fields (Name, Surname, email, State, Address...) to uppercase.

I mean no CSS transform, like `text-transform: uppercase`; but transform in PHP before they go to the database. (Filter)

I can't find how I can applicate this PHP function, string `strtoupper ( string $string )`.

I have created a filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

with a function

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields = strtoupper($fields);
     return $fields;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: *waves hand* this isn't the filter you are looking for (young padwan)... you can change the field labels and placeholders etc. using this filter - how the fields are displayed at checkout. It will not affect how these fields filled in by the customer are save in the database...

Comment: oh and btw woocommerce questions will usually get downvoted here because they are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

First add the following code (and probably the WC Test Payment Gateway) and do a test order to get a list of all the data keys that are set in the order process via the `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` filter:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation','custom_modify_order',10,1);
function custom_modify_order($posted) {
    foreach ($posted as $key => $value) {$data .= $key.":".$value.PHP_EOL;}
    $fh = fopen(get_stylesheet_directory().'/orderdebug.txt','w');
    fwrite($fh,$data); fclose($fh);
    return $posted;
}
```

Then when you have identified which keys you want to transform by checking `orderdebug.txt` (output in your current theme's root directory), you can remove the previous code and implement the following code via the `woocommerce_process_checkout_field_`* filters:

```
// add the desired keys to this array in the following format, eg.
$uppercasefields = array('billing_first_name','billing_last_name');

foreach ($uppercasefields as $fieldkey) {
    add_filter('woocommerce_process_checkout_field_'.$fieldkey,'custom_field_to_uppercase');
}  
function custom_field_to_uppercase($value) {return strtoupper($value);}
```

(see function `process_checkout` of `woocoomerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php` if you want to see where this filter is applied)

**EDIT**: Seems like the keys are listed here anyway:

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

So you might be able to skip the first step, but it's still a worthy debugging experience. :-)

Comment: Emails are *NOT* case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Aşağıdaki kodu function dosyasına eklediğinizde ilk harf büyük olarak düzenlenmiş olacaktır,

```
    function add_custom_js_to_footer() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Bu kod, sayfa tamamen yüklendiğinde çalışacak
            $("#billing_first_name").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var words = value.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                $(this).val(words.join(' '));
            });

            $("#billing_last_name").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var words = value.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                $(this).val(words.join(' '));
            });
            
            $("#billing_address_1").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var words = value.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                $(this).val(words.join(' '));
            });
            
            $("#billing_address_2").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var words = value.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                $(this).val(words.join(' '));
            });
                    
            $("#billing_company").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var words = value.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                $(this).val(words.join(' '));
            });
            
            $("#billing_vergi_dairesi").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var words = value.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                $(this).val(words.join(' '));
            });
            
            $("#billing_city").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var words = value.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                $(this).val(words.join(' '));
            });
            
            $("#order_comments").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var words = value.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                $(this).val(words.join(' '));
            });
            
            $("#billing_email").on("blur", function() {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); // Küçük harfe çevir
                $(this).val(value);
            });
            
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_custom_js_to_footer');
```